# Condition in 'if' Logic controller jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter

'if' controller is skipped.

I need to check size of contents in a variable, and if size > 0 action should be taken

```
 ${__groovy(${WorkflowActivities}.size() > 0)}
```

This is the condition added in if controller

But if controller is not working

Comment: How did you save `WorkflowActivities`?

Comment: Json Extractor, this variable is visible in debug sampler

Comment: Show the value in debug sampler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Although below condition works for me, try a "Java" version

```
${__groovy(Integer.parseInt(vars.get("WorkflowActivities"))  > 0)}
```

I think your value is a number saved as String when extract from JSON. So you just need to convert it:

```
${__groovy(vars.get("WorkflowActivities") as int  > 0)}
```

Comment: thats right, its stored as String. but i see this in logs.   Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script118.groovy: 1: unexpected token: > @ line 1, column 47.

Comment: @Sriyad condition works for me, but try a more "Java" version `${__groovy(Integer.parseInt(vars.get("WorkflowActivities"))  > 0)}`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this function, it should work.

```
${__groovy(vars.get("WorkflowActivities").size() > 0)}
```

For more references, please check this [link](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

Comment: thanks, but condition is not evaluated. if is 'true' in all cases.

Comment: ok, I noted that the variable is stored as String. Can we implement size() function on it?